# Passing callback from action into Epic

Tags: javascript, observable, redux-observable

I am currently using an action creator to pass a callback function into an Epic, however I run into the common error: `Actions must be plain JavaScript objects...`

Is there a way of executing the callback and still proceeding with the observable inside an Epic? I've also tried using the curly braces and an explicit return to assign the chain to a variable and return it after invoking the callback, but I run into the same problem.

Code:

```
const selectItem = (item, activeRow, cb) => ({ type: SELECT_ITEM, activeRow, item, cb });

const selectItemEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(SELECT_ITEM)
    .mergeMap(action =>
        Observable.forkJoin(
            ajax.getJSON(...),
            ajax.getJSON(...)
        )
        .map(res => returnSelectedItem({ ...res[0].response, ...res[1].response }, action.activeRow))
        .map(() => action.cb()) // failing here
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType(SELECT_ITEM))
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` operator is meant as a 1:1 mapping--so it expects you to return something in your projection function. Right now you're returning what ever the result of `action.cb()` is. If this isn't an action (e.g. it returns nothing/`undefined`), that would be the source of your error.

It's not 100% clear what `returnSelectedItems()` returns, if this actually returns the action you want to emit from your epic, you could instead use the `do` operator to make the `action.cb()` side effect without affecting the actual values flowing through the stream.

```
const selectItemEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(SELECT_ITEM)
    .mergeMap(action =>
        Observable.forkJoin(
            ajax.getJSON(...),
            ajax.getJSON(...)
        )
        .map(res => returnSelectedItem({ ...res[0].response, ...res[1].response }, action.activeRow))
        .do(() => action.cb()) // do, instead of map
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType(SELECT_ITEM))
    );
```

Comment: How can i implement this in redux-observable v1?

Comment: @MasterLuV the same except using RxJS v6 pipeable operators or using rxjs-compat if you want to use older prototype-based methods.